# XML Parsing Query Linq for searching the required

Tags: java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<MAGIC name="WI -Woekitem">
    <TORCH value="bcy/me.08" />
    <TORCH value="bcy/me.71" />
    <TORCH value="bcy/me.09" />
    <TORCH value="bcy/me.108" />
</MAGIC>
```

Likewise, I need to do this for every torch name node.

Please help me to do this task

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Why is this taggen with [tag:java]?

Comment: I removed the `java` tag because you're asking a C# solution. Feel free to update the post if it bothers you.

Comment: i like to get it using java dom or sax parser

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(XMLSTRING);

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            node.ChildNodes[i]......
        }
    }
```

Comment: When giving a SO answer, please provide also a description and not only some code. This way people can learn from your answers and not only copy/paste your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex and xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var groups = doc.Descendants("GLOBALLIST").Select(x => new {
                name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                items = x.Elements("LISTITEM")
                  .Select(y => (string)y.Attribute("value"))
                  .Select(y => y.Split(new char[] { '/' }))
                  .Select(y => new { path = y.FirstOrDefault(), name = y.LastOrDefault() })
                  .ToList()
            }).ToList();

            var results = groups.Select(x => new
            {
                name = x.name,
                items = x.items
                    .GroupBy(y => y.path)
                    .Select(y =>
                       y.OrderByDescending(z => GetNumber(z.name))
                       .Take(3).ToList())
                    .ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }

        static int? GetNumber(string input)
        {
            string pattern = @"\d+$";
            string strNumber = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Value;

            int number = 0;
            bool results = int.TryParse(strNumber, out number);
            if (results == false) return null;
            return number;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works with sample xml you posted.  It must means some of the elements to not end wit a number.   When you get the exception you can hover over the variable input to see which line gives the exception.  I will modify code to ignore error.

Comment: can you do the same without using regular expression